# Is a nested loop always reset after its last iteration?

Tags: javascript

When the nested loop is done looping, is the **variable j** going to be reset back to zero? I assume it is, because we start from the beginning again, but I want to make sure that all you experts out there agree with me. Also, where can I find the answer to this in textbooks and not here?

```
const userTextInput = "Hello my name is Luka";
const vowels = ["a", "e", "u", "e", "i"];

for(let i = 0; i <= userTextInput.length; i = i + 1){
  for(let j = 0; j <= vowels.length; j = j + 1){
    if(userTextInput[i] === vowels[j]){
      console.log(vowels[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The simple answer is yes.

Comment: It sounds like you need to really try to understand how code works. You are declaring a variable at the start of a block. That block is being executed multiple times. For each execution you get a new context and a new variable. You could hit F12 and brean on the inner for to verify

Comment: I'm 1 week into my CodeAcademy course @Marie, not yet a master of the jsfiddle

Comment: Gotcha. It may be easier for you to understand and debug if you actually run code on your local machine. Otherwise, you can still click F12 in any web browser and use the debugger there

Comment: I'm running most of "my code" lol...in CodeAcademy and playcode.io
Any books or websites you can recommend, you seem to know your way around javascript-land?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, not quite. When the nested lop finishes, `j` will not be defined. Only when it starts again (for the next iteration of `i`), will `j` then be reset.

For example, the below will give you a `j is not defined` error.

```js
for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++)
  ;
console.log(j);
```

Comment: Do you agree with Maheer Ali's answer?

Comment: added a comment to his answer. but his explanation other than the last bullet point is right on.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps may help you to understand the code:

- The variable `j` is only present inside the the nested loop.
- When the nested loop ends means `j <= vowels.length` becomes `false` the code exits the loop.
- At this point there is no `j`. `j` is destroyed.
- Now the outer for loop in continued again and `i` is incremented.
- This time a new variable `j` is again created and initialized to `0`.
- This happens while `i <= userTextInput.length;` is `true`

Comment: @LukaMomcilovic I just missed `i` in start. I mean `true` not `false`.

Comment: What? How can you mean true and no false?

Comment: As long as i is less than or equal to userTextInput.length, run this code. When i isn't less or when it's equal to userTextInput.length, then do not run this code anymore.

Comment: @LukaMomcilovic The sentence _"As long as i is less than or equal to userTextInput.length, run this code. When i isn't less or when it's equal to userTextInput.length, then do not run this code anymore."_ is completely correct.

Comment: @LukaMomcilovic The code runs until the condition `i<= userTextInput.length;` is `true`. Means if `length` is `5` the code will run for `0...5` but not for `6` because condition gets false.

Comment: I think the issue is `This happens *until* the i <= userTextInput.length; *is true*` is not what you're describing. You probably mean `*while ... is true*` or `*until ... is false*.`

Comment: @junvar Thanks. You are right. Actually I am not native english speaker so I i made this mistake.

Comment: the code runs until «i» is bigger or equal to userTextInput

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, the loop isn't doing anything special here. **You** are resetting the variable every time you enter the loop.

A `for` loop has 3 parts (`for (1; 2; 3) {}`):

1. Run once before starting the loop
2. Condition to check if the loop body should be executed
3. Code to execute after each iteration

So, when you are doing this:

```js
for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {}
```

You are declaring and `j` and setting it to 0. This **always** happens before you enter the loop. Then, the loop body is executed while `j` is less than 5, and after every iteration `j` is incremented by 1.

Because you declared `j` in the `for` statement, it only exists within the `for` loop. When you exit the loop, the variable is gone.

However, even if the variable would still exist outside the loop, you would reset it the next time you enter the loop again, because you're doing `j = 0`.

In this example I'm declaring the variable outside the `for` loop, so it still exists outside the loop:

```js
let j = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (; j < 5; j++) {
        console.log(`iteration ${j}`);
    }
}

console.log(i);
console.log(j);

// Prints:
// iteration 0
// iteration 1
// iteration 2
// iteration 3
// iteration 4
// undefined
// 4
```

I've omitted the first part of the for loop, so `j` is never reset. This causes the inner loop to only run 5 times, which would be 25 times if the variable would be reset every time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is set back to the value you initialized it, everytime the loop starts. For your case, yes it is 0.

Comment: So after the last iteration inside the nested loop. The variable "j", just disappears and is terminated forever?

Comment: Yes, it is only valid in the scope of the nested loop.

Comment: Aha, interesting. Thanks :)